# I am getting repeated input values as an Output when I am trying to get User Input from Prompt box and showing those input values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

**In example - 1 I am getting all the values Entered from the Prompt box.**

//Example - 1

```js
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => {

            let cars = new Array(5);

            for(let get = 0 ; get <= 5 ; get++){

                cars[get] = prompt("Enter Any Values");
            }

            for(let show = 0 ; show <= 5 ; show++ ){

                document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML += `You have Entered : ${cars[show]}<br>`;
            }

            document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = `The Total Values are : ${cars}`;

        }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
    <div id="data1"></div>
    <div id="data2"></div>
```

**I am Facing a Problem in Example - 2 .please tell me Where I did wrong. Thank You..!**

//Example - 2

```js
 document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => {

            let cars = new Array(5);

            for(let get of cars){
                cars[get] = prompt("Enter Any Values");
            }
            for(let show of cars){

                document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML += `You have Entered : ${cars[show]}<br>`;
            }

            document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = `The Total Values are : ${cars}`;

        }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
    <div id="data1"></div>
    <div id="data2"></div>
```

Comment: I believe you're trying to use `for (let show in cars)`

Comment: @HassaanAli, yes after using `for (let show in cars)` i am getting only the last input value and I am getting an empty array in total values.

Comment: let me write a detailed answer for you.

Comment: @HassaanAli, Thank you So much, Sir. It's working fine in traditional for loop (example - 1) but in for-of and for-in loops, I am facing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for of` is for values of array like objectd (**and not their indices**). [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

You use `for in` for indices:

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (const element of array1) {
  console.log(element);
}

for (const element in array1) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Now to answer what is happening in your second code:

`get` is `undefined` every time inside the loop, because the `cars` array is empty. **So there are no values.**
Every time inside your loop this happens :

`cars[undefined] = (your prompt answer)`

And the value of cars[undefined] is getting overwritten too

At this point `cars` is an object with a key `undefined` with value `YOURLASTENTEREDVALUE`.
Later the `for of` loop is run over the `cars` array again to show the values. Now once again `show` is `undefined` inside the loop, **because `cars` is still empty.**

So every time you are doing `cars[undefined]` again. But this time you have a value for it, which will be the last value you have answered and that is being shown.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => {

            let cars = new Array(3);

            for(let get of cars){
                console.log(get);
                cars[get] = prompt("Enter Any Values");
            }

            console.log(Object.keys(cars));
            console.log(Object.values(cars));
            
            console.log(cars[undefined]);
            for(let show of cars){

              console.log(show);  document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML += `You have Entered : ${cars[show]}<br>`;
            }

            document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = `The Total Values are : ${cars}`;

        }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
    <div id="data1"></div>
    <div id="data2"></div>
```

**EDIT**
As requested by OP, one way to fix it:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => {

            let cars = new Array(3).fill(0);
              for(let get in cars){
                cars[get] = prompt("Enter Any Values");
            }

            for(let show in cars){
 document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML += `You have Entered : ${cars[show]}<br>`;
            }

            document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = `The Total Values are : ${cars}`;

        }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
    <div id="data1"></div>
    <div id="data2"></div>
```

Filling array with default `0`s initially so they can be iterated over with `for in`, is one way.

Comment: Thank you sir for sharing detailed information about this problem. Does that mean my approach for the second example was wrong ? is there any way I can get the Correct Output using for-in or for-of loop.

Comment: You can. See edit. Iterating over absolutely empty array of length 5, is giving you problems. Just fill with default value. Please upvote if this helped you